# SuiteScript 2 RESTlet Insufficient Permissions

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a restlet, that returns insufficient permissions even though I have the table on the role with full permissions. The setup for this is the same as one I did yesterday and I just copied and renamed the role. That one works fine. It connects fine and I can get rid of the error by not accessing the table. The table is a custom type, ordinary columns, no segments. I have the permissions in the transactions subtab of the role, I also have 'lists" filled out, along with setup and custom record. The same setup works on my other restlet flawlessly. I can find no difference between the two aside from the tables they access. Yet I have a permissions error. Any help or insight would be appreciated thanks

Edit: Yes I do mean record type when I say table. Here is the paste from postman that gets returned

"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION\",\"message\":\"Permission Violation: You need a higher permission for custom record type Tower Equipment Information to access this page. Please contact your account administrator.\"

Like I said I have the role added to the restlet, I have transactions subtab, lists and setup filled out. The Record type is present in the permissions. I have done restlets before and I had one from the day before to compare to on the same instance that is fine. So I am at a loss. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Sorry, in addition, the call is creating the record

Comment: please rephrase your question. I think you mean record when you say table, etc, etc.  Several short-comings in your question.  tip: perhaps the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when moving a script from Sandbox to Production.

What fixed it for me was setting the "Audience" on the script to allow the token user's Role. I didn't have to do this in Sandbox.

Comment: Thanks, I had re-created everything and got it working, thanks again

Comment: What do you set Audience to?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the permission level you have set into that role, NetSuite basically have 3 types of access levels

1. Full
2. edit
3. view

If you have only view permissions and you re trying to create the record using that role, it may be one of the reasons you re getting INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION

Comment: Hi and thanks, yes it is set to FULL, I have another one RESTlet that is set the same and running fine, this one for whatever reason is not and I was looking for an insight of where else to look. thanks again.